# ntpd in systemd-nspawn

Tags: ntpd, systemd-nspawn

I'm playing with containerizing various parts of my server infrastructure and one of the services I would like to run in container is ntp daemon.

I'm using systemd-nspawn (systemd 233) as a hypervisor as well as init process inside of the containers.

ntpd version is 4.2.8p10.

Every time I try to start ntpd inside of a container it crashes with `cap_set_proc()` operation not permitted error:

```
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728 Fri Oct 20 23:28:39 UTC 2017 (1): Starting
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: Command line: ntpd -g -n -u ntp:ntp
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: Cannot set RLIMIT_MEMLOCK: Operation not permitted
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: proto: precision = 0.335 usec (-21)
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: Listen normally on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1:123
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: Listening on routing socket on fd #18 for interface updates
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: mlockall(): Cannot allocate memory
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: start_kern_loop: ntp_loopfilter.c line 1119: ntp_adjtime: Operation not permitted
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: set_freq: ntp_loopfilter.c line 1082: ntp_adjtime: Operation not permitted
21 Oct 11:10:23 ntpd[51]: cap_set_proc() failed to drop root privs: Operation not permitted
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Building ntpd without capabilities enabled - it starts properly, but still has same `ntp_adjtime` syscall permission issues.
2. Running systemd-nspawn with `--private-users=0` and without `--private-users` at all.
3. Playing with capabilities for systemd-nspawn itself (mainly `CAP_SYS_TIME` and `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`)
4. Playing with capabilities for ntpd inside of the container.

All this gave no positive results and I wonder what am I missing.
Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you don't set capabilities on systemd-nspawn.  You use the `capability` option of systemd-nspawn.

Comment: @sourcejedi I have tried adding both capabilities required by ntpd into `systemd-nspawn` service itself.

Comment: that's also the wrong way to describe what you want to do.  The systemd-nspawn command drops capabilities, according to the option you pass it.  You cannot increase capabilities by setting them on systemd-nspawn.service.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I think I explained it wrong. What I tried is setting capability on the service file for systemd-nspawn on host, passing same capability as `--capability` argument to systemd-nspawn in the host and setting this capability on ntpd service inside of the container. Hope that makes sense.